# org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException - HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications, tomcat6, hibernate-mapping

I am having a problem with HibernateTemplate and I don't know where I am going wrong. I am using Hibernate3 and Tomcat6.
In my DAO, I have functions that try to query the database using a string and they seem to work fine. Like this

```
public AppUser getUserByUserName(String username){
    HibernateTemplate template=new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    try{
        List<AppUser> appList = template.find(" from AppUser as au where au.username=?", username);
        tempUser = appList.get(0);  
        return tempUser;
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Problem in AppUserDao--get byUsername: " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Yet, when I try to query using an integer. Like:

```
public List<AppUser> getAllMerchants(){
    HibernateTemplate template=new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    try{
        List<AppUser> appList = template.find(" from appuser as au where au.securityLevel!=?", 112);
        if(appList.size() > 0)
            return appList;
        else
            return null;
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Problem in AppUserDao--getAllMerchants: " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: appuser is not mapped [ from appuser as au where au.securityLevel!=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: appuser is not mapped [ from appuser as au where au.securityLevel!=?]
```

My entity seems to have the necessary annotations. Since it works for the first function, I don't understand why it doesn't work for the second.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="appuser")
public class AppUser {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private int state;
    private int securityLevel;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator= "idSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="idSeq",sequenceName="app_user_seq_id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name="password_2")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }
    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }
    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public int getSecurityLevel() {
        return securityLevel;
    }
    public void setSecurityLevel(int securityLevel) {
        this.securityLevel = securityLevel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in your code.
In the first function you use "from AppUser " in the second "from appuser".
Try to change the second query to "from AppUser".

Comment: Absolutely right. Hahaha. I guess I just needed fresh eyes. I forgot that I used the @Table annotation. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem. Do not forget to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your answer 
I realised we have to use commandclass name instead of using the table name in the query

```
return getHibernateTemplate().find("from ModuleCommand order by application");
```

ModuleCommand - command class name
app_module - table name.

in bean

```
<bean id="....
.
.
.
<property name="commandClass" value="com.web.mon.thread.ModuleCommand" />
...
</bean>
```